# DPKG failing with fail2ban

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, dpkg

Everything was working fine until I ran an update.  Since the fail2ban package is giving me errors now.  I decided that I would try to uninstall it and then reinstall it again.

So I ran `sudo apt-get remove fail2ban`.  Here was the output that I got.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python-gamin
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fail2ban
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
After this operation, 349 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fail2ban' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 98934 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing fail2ban ...
pycentral: pycentral pkgremove: package fail2ban is not installed
pycentral pkgremove: package fail2ban is not installed
dpkg: error processing fail2ban (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fail2ban
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

About that warning with the files list file for package 'fail2ban', I removed that file in attempt to fix this problem.

I tried to use `sudo apt-get install fail2ban` but it says that it's already on it's newest version.  Even though it's not working.

Here are some other things I've tried.

- `sudo apt-get remove --purge fail2ban`
- `sudo apt-get install --force-yes fail2ban`
- `sudo apt-get remove --force-yes fail2ban`
- `sudo apt-get install fail2ban --reinstall`

I have no idea what I should do from here.  Any help with this would be awesome.

I'm running Raspbian Wheezy 7 on the RPi 2.

Comment: You don't say what happens when you run this  sudo apt-get install --force-yes fail2ban

Comment: @SteveRobillard It says it's already installed, on it's newest version.  I've messed up the manager pretty badly.  I might have to restore from an earlier backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally got it working again.  I downloaded the fail2ban package from the debian package repository using `wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fail2ban/fail2ban_0.8.13-1_all.deb`.

Once the package was downloaded, I used `sudo dpkg -i fail2ban_0.8.13-1_all.deb`.  Then following that command, I used `sudo apt-get -f install`.

And finally, I used `sudo apt-get install fail2ban`.  Everything seems to be working great now.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit too late, but `sudo apt-get install fail2ban --reinstall` would have installed fail2ban even if it is already installed.

This should have the same effect as what you finally did.

Comment: This actually didn't work.  Sorry for not including this in my question, but it did end up returning the same error.  There was some major problems with my package manager.